# DNS not working after domain trasnfered to AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, transfer

I have two domains in AWS Route53, both setup with the same DNS entries.
First, that I have registered through Route53 works perfectly fine, while the second, which I have transferred from another provider (originally registered with wordpress) isn't working.
Do you have any idea what's wrong?

```
> nslookup ngschool.eu DNS 
Server:     DNS
Address:    192.168.3.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ngschool.eu
Address: 89.173.206.9

> nslookup bioinfoexpert.com DNS 
Server:     DNS
Address:    192.168.3.7#53

** server can't find bioinfoexpert.com: SERVFAIL
```

[image]

**EDIT**
So there are two problems:
1. after domain transfer, you need to update Name Servers in `Registered Domains > Your domain > Add/Edit Name Servers`, so they match the entries newly created in `Hosted zones`
2. reset you DNS cache

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong that can be seen from the outside (that is, from my point of view both your domains work fine). What may have happened for you is that the resolver your `nslookup` program talked to had the old information cached, so it tried talking to the old servers, who said `SERVFAIL` since they are no longer authoritative for your domain.